# InvalidKeyException: Key Spec Not Recognised

Tags: java, linux, bouncycastle, pgp

I'm getting a

> InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters

when trying to run a web app that is was a deployed WAR. I am hosting it on Tomcat in a Linux environment. I have already put the two UnlimitedJCEPolicy files into the destination `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.55.x86_64/jre/lib/security`, and it seems that the error is still occuring. NOTE that this only is thrown when I am running in the linux environment. Locally, it works fine. Here is my code:

```
public static final void decryptFile(File inputFile, File outputFile) throws 
IOException, PGPException {
    // Add Bouncy Castle provider
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    // Grab secret key that's in folder with AE classes
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(Env.getSecretKeyAE());
    log.debug("Resource: " + Env.getSecretKeyAE());
    File keyFileName = resource.getFile();
    log.debug("Key File Name: " + keyFileName);
    // Decryption password
    String pass = "pass";
    char[] passwd = pass.toCharArray();

    // Read files into streams
    log.info("Reading files into streams");
    InputStream keyIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(keyFileName));
    InputStream in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(new BufferedInputStream(new 
FileInputStream(inputFile)));

    // I don't even know what these do
    PGPObjectFactory pgpObjFactory = new PGPObjectFactory(in);
    PGPEncryptedDataList pgpEncryptedDataList = null;

    Object o = pgpObjFactory.nextObject();
    log.info("Checking instance of PGPEncryptedDataList");
    if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList) {
        pgpEncryptedDataList = (PGPEncryptedDataList)o;
    }
    else {
        pgpEncryptedDataList = (PGPEncryptedDataList)pgpObjFactory.nextObject();
    }

    // This will be the PGPPrivateKey we use to decrypt
    log.info("Initializing secret key");
    PGPPrivateKey secretKey = null;
    PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData publicKeyEncryptedData = null;
    PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSecretKeyRingCollection = new    
PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(keyIn));

    // This iterates the key file as if it has many keys, this file has only one
    // This is the only way I could find to construct a PGPPrivateKey
    log.info("Iterating through key file");
    Iterator<?> it = pgpEncryptedDataList.getEncryptedDataObjects();
    while(it.hasNext() && secretKey == null) {
        publicKeyEncryptedData = (PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData) it.next();
        PGPSecretKey pgpSecKey = 
pgpSecretKeyRingCollection.getSecretKey(publicKeyEncryptedData.getKeyID());

        if (pgpSecKey != null) {
            Provider provider = Security.getProvider("BC");
            secretKey = pgpSecKey.extractPrivateKey(new   

JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder(new  
JcaPGPDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider(provider)
.build()).setProvider(provider).build(passwd));
           }
    }
    log.info("PGPPrivateKey has been constructed");
    if (secretKey == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("secret key for message not found.");
    }
    log.info("Secret Key found!");

    if(publicKeyEncryptedData == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("cannot continue with null public key encryption 
data.");
    }
    log.info("Public Key Encrypted Data found!");

    // More stuff I don't fully understand, I think this is just standard way to   
decrypt files once the above is all set up
    log.info("Starting actual decryption");
    //get data stream where our publicKeyDataDecrypterFactory sets ours provider to BC 
and we build our secretKey
    //secretkey is our PGPPrivateKey

    log.info("start");

    //=====================================================================
    //ERROR IS OCCURRING HERE
    InputStream clear = publicKeyEncryptedData.getDataStream(new  
JcePublicKeyDataDecryptorFactoryBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(secretKey));
    log.info("1");
    PGPObjectFactory plainFact = new PGPObjectFactory(clear);
    log.info("2");
    PGPCompressedData compressedData = (PGPCompressedData)plainFact.nextObject();
    log.info("3");
    InputStream compressedStream = new 
BufferedInputStream(compressedData.getDataStream());
    log.info("4");
    PGPObjectFactory pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(compressedStream);
    log.info("5");
    Object message = pgpFact.nextObject();
    log.info("6");

    if (message instanceof PGPLiteralData) {
        log.info("Our message is an instance of PGP Literal Data.");
        PGPLiteralData literalData = (PGPLiteralData)message;
        InputStream literalDataInputStream = literalData.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        Streams.pipeAll(literalDataInputStream, out);
        out.close();
    }
    else if (message instanceof PGPOnePassSignatureList) {
        log.error("encrypted message contains a signed message - not literal data.");
        throw new PGPException("encrypted message contains a signed message - not  

literal data.");
    }
    else {
        log.error("message is not a simple encrypted file - type unknown.");
        throw new PGPException("message is not a simple encrypted file - type  
unknown.");
    }
    log.info("Checking if public key encrypted data is integrity protected");
    if (publicKeyEncryptedData.isIntegrityProtected()) {
        if (!publicKeyEncryptedData.verify()) {
            throw new PGPException("message failed integrity check");
        }
    }

    keyIn.close();
    in.close();
}
```

Using logs, I was able to find that the error was occurring when

```
InputStream clear = publicKeyEncryptedData.getDataStream(new  
JcePublicKeyDataDecryptorFactoryBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(secretKey));
```

But I have no clue why. Like I said, I already placed the JCEUnlimited files appropriately and the error still occurs.

**EDIT** I fixed the illegal key size problem, but am now getting "key spec not recognized"

**EDIT** More elaboration on the error "key spec not recognized":
So as I said, Illegal key size is gone, but "key spec not recognized" seems to be a problem still. The weird thing is that my encryptFile method works perfectly, but decryptFile is throwing the error. I'm not entirely sure why. Before I left work, I tested one more time and it seems that the error wasn't thrown. I almost seems like this error occurs randomly depending on the deployment of the WAR to tomcat. If I deploy my WAR, the error wont occur at some points, but if I undeploy and redeploy with an updated WAR file, the error is thrown. I have no clue what is causing this, and the based off research no one really knows either. Apparently this used to be a bug in Bouncy Castle before 1.5, but 1.5 is the version I'm running so that's not the problem. I will post if I find anything that can possibly fix this error.

Comment: Because I was using Tomcat, my java home was actually within my opt folder. The exact location I had to put the UnlimitedJCEPolicy files was /opt/jre1.7.0_60/lib/security. After putting the files there, and redeploying my war file, I was not experiencing this problem anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the error "Illegal key size or default parameters", I simply had to put the UnlimitedJCEPolicy files in my working java directory, /opt/jre1.7.0_60/lib/security. After putting the files there, and redeploying my war file, I was not experiencing this problem anymore.

To prevent the "key spec not recognized" error, I had to restart my tomcat server when redeploying my WAR file.

Answer (score 4):

To solve:

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: key spec not recognised

Modify security providers:

```
sudo nano $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security
```

Add security provider:

```
security.provider.10=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Copy `bcprov-jdk15on-1.54.jar` to:

```
$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/bcprov-jdk15on-1.54.jar
```

Restart Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList) {
        pgpEncryptedDataList = (PGPEncryptedDataList)o;
```

if o is already an instance of PGPEncryptedDataList, why are you casting it to PGPEncryptedDataLIST?

I don't know enough about the specifics of what you're doing so I just figured I'd provide some general code analysis. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: To be honest, this was a former co-worker, so I myself cant even tell you why it's like that. Thanks for bringing it to my attention though!