# java Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Cannot decode named group: x25519

Tags: java, bouncycastle, java-module, java-security, jlink

I need some help.

I writing a JavaFX app which uses java kubernetes client https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java which in turn uses bouncyCastle.

When I run the app from Intellij everything works. However when I package the app with jlink-plugin and then run it - it fails with the error:

```
Caused by: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: Message: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Cannot decode named group: x25519
HTTP response code: 0
HTTP response body: null
HTTP response headers: null
        at io.github.vcvitaly.merged.module@1.0-SNAPSHOT/io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:1032)
        at io.github.vcvitaly.merged.module@1.0-SNAPSHOT/io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.listNamespaceWithHttpInfo(CoreV1Api.java:24473)
        at io.github.vcvitaly.merged.module@1.0-SNAPSHOT/io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.access$40900(CoreV1Api.java:77)
        at io.github.vcvitaly.merged.module@1.0-SNAPSHOT/io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api$APIlistNamespaceRequest.execute(CoreV1Api.java:24638)
        at io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp@1.0-SNAPSHOT/io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.client.impl.KubeClientImpl.getNamespaces(KubeClientImpl.java:69)
        ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Cannot decode named group: x25519
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:365)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.KeyShareExtension$SHKeyShareConsumer.consume(KeyShareExtension.java:682)
```

I was able to connect via debug and the causing error at KeyShareExtension$SHKeyShareConsumer.consume is:
`java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: key spec not recognized`

[That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810805/invalidkeyexception-key-spec-not-recognised) answer suggests to add a security provider which I tried doing two ways with no success:

1. Add `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());` to the main class
2. add `security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider` to `build/image/lib/security/java.security`

The immportant moment is that I had to add `'--ignore-signing-information'` to jlink options because otherwise it was failing with:

```
Error: signed modular JAR /home/vcvitaly/IdeaProjects/k8cp/build/jlinkbase/jlinkjars/bcpkix-jdk18on-1.77.jar
is currently not supported, use --ignore-signing-information to suppress error
```

This is my build.gradle

```
import org.openjfx.gradle.JavaFXPlatform

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.1.0'
    id "com.google.osdetector" version "1.7.3"
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '3.0.1'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "8.6"
}

group 'io.github.vcvitaly'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.10.2'
    platform = getPlatform()
    javaVer = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = javaVer
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp'
    mainClass = 'io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.App'
}

javafx {
    version = javaVer
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.2')
    implementation('net.synedra:validatorfx:0.4.0') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }
    implementation('org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-javafx:12.3.1')
    implementation 'org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-fontawesome-pack:12.3.1'
    implementation 'org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-fontawesome5-pack:12.3.1'
    implementation 'org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-material2-pack:12.3.1'
//    implementation('org.kordamp.bootstrapfx:bootstrapfx-core:0.4.0')

    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.5.2'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.12'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.5.2'

    implementation ("io.kubernetes:client-java:20.0.0") {
        exclude group: "com.google.code.findbugs", module: "jsr305"
        exclude group: "com.amazonaws", module: "aws-java-sdk-sts"
    }

    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:${junitVersion}"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}"

    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.11.0'
    testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.25.1"
    testImplementation "org.testfx:testfx-junit5:4.0.18"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = [
//            '--strip-debug', // TODO uncomment
            '--compress', '2',
            '--no-header-files',
            '--no-man-pages'
//            '--ignore-signing-information'
    ]
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}

tasks.register('dist') {
    dependsOn clean, jlinkZip
    description "Calls clean and then jlinkZip"
}

configurations
        .matching(it -> it.name.contains("downloadSources"))
        .configureEach {
    attributes {
        attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Usage, Usage.JAVA_RUNTIME))
        attribute(OperatingSystemFamily.OPERATING_SYSTEM_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(OperatingSystemFamily, platform.osFamily))
        attribute(MachineArchitecture.ARCHITECTURE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(MachineArchitecture, platform.arch))
    }
}

def getPlatform() {
    return JavaFXPlatform.detect(osdetector);
}
```

and my module-info:

```
module io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires java.annotation;
//    requires jsr305;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires net.synedra.validatorfx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome5;

    requires org.slf4j;
    requires ch.qos.logback.core;
    requires ch.qos.logback.classic;

    requires static lombok;
    requires io.kubernetes.client.java;
    requires io.kubernetes.client.java.api;

    requires org.apache.commons.io;
    requires org.yaml.snakeyaml;
    requires com.google.gson;
    requires kotlin.stdlib;
    requires org.apache.commons.lang3;
    requires org.bouncycastle.pkix;
    requires org.bouncycastle.provider;
    requires org.bouncycastle.util;

    requires jdk.jdwp.agent;

    opens io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp to javafx.fxml;
    exports io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp;
    exports io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.controller;
    exports io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.controller.menu;
    exports io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.controller.pane;
    exports io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.controller.init;
    exports io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.domain;
    exports io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.enumeration;
    exports io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.util;
    exports io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.exception;
    opens io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.controller to javafx.fxml;
    opens io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.controller.menu to javafx.fxml;
    opens io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.controller.init to javafx.fxml;
    opens io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.controller.pane to javafx.fxml;
    opens io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.util to javafx.fxml;
}
```

Any thougths?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [page](https://sagebionetworks.jira.com/wiki/spaces/PLFM/pages/2606268806/Java+11+Migration) which says

> Since the error pointed to an algorithm mismatch somewhere in the
> code the security providers must have been altered.

The culprit was a static initialization in the DockerTokenUtil class:

```
static {
    Security.removeProvider("SunEC");
    Security.removeProvider("EC");
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

This piece of code would remove the default providers globally and
replace it with the bouncy castle implementation, since x255519 is
an EC then the mismatch was thrown because the Bouncy Castle
implementation didn’t match it.

I made a guess and was able to resolve it by adding to module-info

```
requires jdk.crypto.ec;
```